# SearchListBinary function is not working to search a Vector

Tags: c++, vector, binary-search

Here are some instructions I was given:

Create two regular c-type functions that take in an integer vector by reference, searches for a particular int target and then returns an iterator pointing to the target. Implement a linear search and a binary search.

```
    vector<int>::iterator searchListBinary(vector<int>& arg, int target) {

    //vector<int>::iterator itrIndex = arg.begin();
    vector<int>::iterator first = arg.begin();
    vector<int>::iterator last = arg.end();
    vector<int>::iterator mid = first + (last - first) / 2;


    while (first <= last){  //while there is a space to search for 

        if (*mid == target) { //If middle value is target

            return (mid);  //return the value of iterator.
        }

        else if (target < *mid) { //This means that the target is on the left side of the the vector, 
                                  //Middle value is larger than the targeted value. 

            last = mid - 1;

        }

        else {

            first = mid + 1;  //outputting 707 
        }

    } 
    //if the code gets here, that means the 
    //target value was not in the vector
    
    return(arg.end());
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "not working".

Comment: Look for a bug in the place where you calculate the midpoint of the new smaller interval.